# Compute rolling sum shifted for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

My goal is to perform a groupby, then creating rolling total stats and then shift. I need it to shift the first instance of each unique player. Right now it is shifting the entire dataframe once, and not doing it for each grouped player.

Original Data -

```
    player   date          won
0   A        2016-01-11    0
1   A        2016-02-01    0
2   A        2016-02-01    1
3   A        2016-02-01    1
4   A        2016-10-24    0
5   A        2016-10-31    0
6   A        2018-10-22    0
7   B        2016-10-24    0
8   B        2016-10-24    1
9   B        2017-11-13    0
```

Things I've tried -

## 1

```
temp = temp_master.groupby('player', sort=False)[count_fields].rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum().shift(1).reset_index(drop=True)    
temp = temp.add_suffix('_total')   
temp['won_total'].head(10)  
 0    NaN
 1    0.0
 2    0.0
 3    1.0
 4    2.0
 5    2.0
 6    2.0
 7    2.0
 8    0.0
 9    1.0
```

## 2

```
temp = temp_master.groupby('player', sort=False)[count_fields].shift(1).rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(drop=True) 
temp = temp.add_suffix('_total') 
temp['won_total'].head(10)
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
9    3.0
```

## 3

```
temp = temp_master.groupby('player', sort=False)[count_fields].rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum().reset_index(drop=True)    
temp = temp.add_suffix('_total')
temp = temp.shift(1)  
temp['won_total'].head(10)  
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    0.0
9    1.0
```

This is what I need the results to be -

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    NaN
8    0.0
9    1.0
```

index #7 should equal NaN. It should be the first instance of player B and I want it to shift at the first instance of every new player to sumarrize stats by player.

index 8 should equal 0

index 9 should equal 1

It looks like attempt #1 & #3 is close but it's not assigning the NaN value on the new player. #3 isn't doing a groupedby player anymore though so I know that won't really work.

Also, this will be done on a good amount of data (around 100K-300K rows) and the 'count_fields' column contains around 3K-4K columns that I am calculating. Just something to be aware of.

Any ideas on how to create running stats by player and shift down at for every player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `apply` here , this two functions are not chain under the `groupby` object , sum is under the `groupby` , but `shift` will implement to the result after sum which is whole columns

```
temp = temp_master.groupby('player', sort=False)['won'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum().shift(1))\
    .reset_index(drop=True)    
temp
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    NaN
8    0.0
9    1.0
Name: won, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option if you don't want to use `apply` is to layer a second `groupby` call and perform the shifting:

```
(df.groupby('player', sort=False)
   .won.rolling(10, min_periods=1)
   .sum()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .shift()
   .reset_index(drop=True))

0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    NaN
8    0.0
9    1.0
Name: won, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This solution worked as well and was about the same speed according to %%timeit